# Is it possible to threshold the maximum GPU usage per user?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

We have Ubuntu 18.04 installed machine with an RTX 2080 Ti GPU with about 3-4 users using it remotely. Is it possible to give a maximum threshold GPU usage per user (say 60%) so any other could use the rest?

We are running tensorflow deep learning models if it helps to suggest an alternative.

Comment: don't hesitate to answer your own question if you have found a solution or a workaround, as this will help people with the same problem. (and it will give you some nice points (: )

Comment: Apologies for not answering the question and kudos for the reminder @CiprianTomoiagă. Please follow the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies for taking so long to come back here to answer the question, even after figuring out a way to do this.

It is indeed possible to threshold the GPU usage with tensorflow's `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction`. [Hence I edited the question]

Following snippet assigns 46% of GPU memory for the user.

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.46)
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    ############
    #Training happens here#
    ############
```

Currently, we have 2 users using the same GPU simultaneously without any issues. We have assigned 46% per each. Make sure you don't make it 50-50%  (aborted, core dumped error occurs if you do so). Try to keep around 300MB memory in idle.

And as a matter of fact, this GPU division does not slow down the training process. Surprisingly, it offers about the same speed as if the full memory is used, at least according to our experience. Although, this may change with high dimensional data.

Comment: can you do this transparently to the user? or you have to ask them nicely to not forget to use the `gpu_options` when instantiating a new session ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I asked the question after doing some research and still couldn't find anything. So we had to limit the GPU usage from the code.  Please post here if you figure out a way to automatically assign the GPU memory.